# one to many scenario on Wifi Direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am trying to create a sample of WifiDirect based on the one which is provided by google. i am trying to implement following scenario.

its a one to many wifi connection.

for example,

1. A is the group owner
2. A discovers that there are 3 other nodes named X,  Y, and  Z.
3. A will make connection to all three nodes.
4. A will send files over all three node.

But I think after exploring I came to know that X , Y and Z should make connection to group owner i.e. A. so somewhere I am confused how to implement the one to many scenario using wifi direct on andorid.

would it be `A to X , Y , Z` or `X , Y , Z to A`

Comment: Hi @Hunt were you successful in getting this done? I need something similar.

Comment: yeah it is very much possible by creating group but the issue with the wifi direct is , it does not last for long.

Comment: @Hunt would you recommend other methods for one to many then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)The group owner creates a "group", it is the place where he states that he is the ONE.

2)The peers see that such group is created and they MAKE the INITIATION for the connection.

3)The group owner can approve or decline to add the peer(that has made the first connection) to the group.

But, it is only the first time, it is only the initiation of the connection that they make.

4)From now on the group owner can send information to the peers and they can send him information, too.

Note that it was initially called WiFi peer-to-peer.